# How to stop music when embedded youtube video starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML site with which music starts on entering, but I want it to stop when the user clicks play on the youtube video that is embedded onto my website.. so it makes the background music and the video music not be able to run simultaneously because that's annoying.

Any idea on how to do that? or if there is any solution for this problem?

Comment: This does not answer your question at all and I don't know your specific application, but I would like to cast my vote against using background music at all on your website. That's annoying in itself.

Comment: automatic background music is a thing of the past... don't annoy users

Comment: Background music on any website = close ASAP while cursing the designer. Depending on the video player, you can use JavaScript to hook into a "start" event of the player and to stop the audio.

Comment: Also want to advise against background music. If I'm listening to my own mp3s and looking for something online, the last thing I want is some other site's music getting in the way. Background music is also a major accessibility issue for screenreader users who are relying on using text-to-speech. (Similar issue applies to auto-play videos.)

Comment: What's annoying is when people ask very vague and broad questions on a site for programmers. Perhaps you could take a moment and turn this into a real question.

Comment: Guys I do agree with you, it's annoying and I do not like it.. but I'm a web designer and the client asked me to add background music.. would anyone help please?

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand my question? my question is very clear.. no ?

Comment: Thanks for the one who edited my question, is it clear enough now?

Comment: SO is Q&A. Not general discussion, guys. He obviously gets the fact that it's a bad idea. Otherwise he would go to "Code Review" or something like that. If you have an answer, I believe you should answer it. If not, leave it up to the first guy to give the obvious opinion.

Comment: question isn't clear at all..no. A lot depends on player you are using. Create a proper question that includes code and a demo

Answer (score 3):

Detect the player's state change (`onStateChange` event) using JavaScript: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events

If the video is loaded using an `iframe` (as the comments indicate) see [Guide for YouTube `iframe` embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) (note the code sample which detects player events).

**Example**

```
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      // code to stop the audio player should probably go here
    }
  }
```

When the player starts, use JavaScript to stop the audio. You haven't told us how it is embedded into the page, but nearly any player can be stopped with script (even `bgsound` can be hacked).

And encourage your client to not auto-play music when the page loads. From a pure business standpoint, it can cost you customers.

Comment: Will I be asking too much if I ask you to tell me what to add step by step please? and this is how i embedded the video: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videolink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: This is a good walkthrough for controlling videos embedded with `iframes`: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference. If you get stuck on a particular point, open a new question. Users on this site like to see specific questions with code samples.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I have added the code you gave me, and I added this in the // code to stop the audio player should probably go here : `function stop() {
document.getElementById("sound").src = "";
}` and this is the bg music code: `<audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="music.mp3" id="sound">
      <source src="music.ogg" id="sound">
</audio>` but its still not stopping the music when I play the video

Comment: If you put an `alert()` in `onPlayerStateChange()` is it shown? First step is to ensure that the event is firing correctly.