# onclick embeded video , background music stop

Tags: javascript, html, audio, embed

My problem is exactly like this post

> [How to stop music when embedded youtube video starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719701/how-to-stop-music-when-embedded-youtube-video-starts?rq=1)

But it doesn't solve my problem.

My html for music :

```
        <audio id="myAudio" autoplay> 
              <source src="music/Morning-Sun.wav">
        </audio>
```

embed video :

```
           <div class="video">
                <div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
                    thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'; 
                    document.getElementById('iframe').src = 
                    document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');">    
                    <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="images/video-thumb-2.jpg" alt="Walk Through" />
                </div>
                <div id="thevideo" style="display: none; width:100%;">
                    <div class="embed-container">
                        <iframe id="iframe" width="900" height="506" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i5e03Re96wY?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=dark;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0"frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[edit]

```
<div class="video">
                    <div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
                        thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'; 
                        document.getElementById('iframe').src = 
                        document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1'); 
                        var aud = document.getElementById('myAudio'); aud.pause();">    
                        <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="images/video-thumb-2.jpg" alt="Walk Through" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="thevideo" style="display: none; width:100%;">
                        <div class="embed-container">
                            <iframe id="iframe" width="900" height="506" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i5e03Re96wY?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=dark;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0"frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, (aside from boohiss for having background music), you are better off to create a function rather than include a string of javascript in your html. You made the error of not defining 'thevid' as a variable, which i corrected. You weren't calling the audio at any point either to stop it, so i created a variable to find it by id, and pause it on video play.

Naturally my sound is different, and as it is short i have set it to loop, but you can easily amend this.

Hope this helps you out :)

```js
var thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
var thumb=document.getElementById('thumb');
var playing = 1;
function playvid(){

thevid.style.display='block'; 
thumb.style.display='none';                    document.getElementById('iframe').src = 
                    document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');
var aud = document.getElementById('myAudio');

aud.pause();
playing = 0;

thevid.onended = function(){
  aud.play();
};
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <audio id="myAudio" autoplay loop> 
      <source src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/monkey.mp3">
 </audio>
 <div class="video">
                <div id="thumb">   
                    <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="images/video-thumb-2.jpg" alt="Walk Through" onclick='playvid();' />
                </div>
                <div id="thevideo" style="display: none; width:100%;">
                    <div class="embed-container">
                        <iframe id="iframe" width="900" height="506" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i5e03Re96wY?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=dark;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0"frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YYdMz.jpg) there is a problem over "thevid"s style. after i put it on javascript file .

Comment: @Zhun did you remove the id "thevideo" from your html perchance? btw its 5:50 am here

Comment: @Zhun it's pretty obvious that it works, with the given examples; it's obviously some small error in the html that is causing this problem. You can post your html if you like

Comment: Alright @RachelGallen its worked, I apply the code to html and it works.
Everything works so well , and if I pause the video the bg music resume, is it possible ? THANKS ALOT !

Comment: @Zhun the edited code will play background music when the video ends

Comment: erm I don't think the resume function work. The music doesn't resume after video ends. I also tried use "onpause", nothing happended too .

Comment: A. I did the code at 6am (when ID just woken up) and b. I see you still haven't created a function.  If you aren't even going to use JavaScript correctly, don't expect much more help.